# Portable version of pyCrypto? - Python

Tags: python, django, aes, portability, pycrypto

does a portable version of pyCrypto exist? would one be easy to create?

---

Help would be awesome!

Comment: What do you mean by "portable"? What environment(s) do you want to use it on?

Comment: Windows Server 2005, portable as in using a "drag and drop" folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't quite understand what you mean by portable or by using a "drag and drop" folder. But pre-built binaries for Windows can be found [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto).

Comment: I think he means something that doesn't need to be installed (late, I know).